# How do i hide a portion of a div in CSS/React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to do something like this where initially the entire div is shown (all the text is shown) and at the bottom you can click a button that says "show less" and only 300px of the content of the div will now be shown and the button changes to "show more".

```html
<div className="bodyText">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed nunc sit amet est sollicitudin tempus. Etiam ultricies velit dolor, et rutrum ante fermentum quis. In enim nibh, imperdiet id pulvinar at, euismod id justo. Sed nisl eros, viverra ut purus et, hendrerit dictum risus. Proin ut massa libero. Vestibulum eget nisi laoreet arcu vulputate mollis non eu ipsum. Praesent tempus ut felis id consequat. Duis tincidunt id nulla vitae suscipit. Sed nec erat varius turpis elementum mattis at eu dolor.

  Pellentesque ante orci, molestie ut tortor et, egestas varius felis. Morbi ultricies, nisl ac fringilla placerat, ante risus posuere lacus, vitae tempus lacus tellus a erat. Quisque lacinia laoreet purus sit amet facilisis. Praesent eu elementum leo. Phasellus consectetur, sapien non accumsan pulvinar, orci eros vehicula est, eget molestie diam dolor id massa. Proin ligula libero, tristique id finibus at, laoreet ac nisi. Morbi porttitor enim non turpis bibendum, id porta libero consectetur. In mattis lectus et urna luctus eleifend.

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example how to do that.

```html
<div class="bodyText">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sed nunc sit amet est sollicitudin tempus. Etiam ultricies velit dolor, et rutrum ante fermentum quis. In enim nibh, imperdiet id pulvinar at, euismod id justo. Sed nisl eros, viverra ut purus et, hendrerit dictum risus. Proin ut massa libero. Vestibulum eget nisi laoreet arcu vulputate mollis non eu ipsum. Praesent tempus ut felis id consequat. Duis tincidunt id nulla vitae suscipit. Sed nec erat varius turpis elementum mattis at eu dolor.

  Pellentesque ante orci, molestie ut tortor et, egestas varius felis. Morbi ultricies, nisl ac fringilla placerat, ante risus posuere lacus, vitae tempus lacus tellus a erat. Quisque lacinia laoreet purus sit amet facilisis. Praesent eu elementum leo. Phasellus consectetur, sapien non accumsan pulvinar, orci eros vehicula est, eget molestie diam dolor id massa. Proin ligula libero, tristique id finibus at, laoreet ac nisi. Morbi porttitor enim non turpis bibendum, id porta libero consectetur. In mattis lectus et urna luctus eleifend.

   Pellentesque ante orci, molestie ut tortor et, egestas varius felis. Morbi ultricies, nisl ac fringilla placerat, ante risus posuere lacus, vitae tempus lacus tellus a erat. Quisque lacinia laoreet purus sit amet facilisis. Praesent eu elementum leo. Phasellus consectetur, sapien non accumsan pulvinar, orci eros vehicula est, eget molestie diam dolor id massa. Proin ligula libero, tristique id finibus at, laoreet ac nisi. Morbi porttitor enim non turpis bibendum, id porta libero consectetur. In mattis lectus et urna luctus eleifend.

   Pellentesque ante orci, molestie ut tortor et, egestas varius felis. Morbi ultricies, nisl ac fringilla placerat, ante risus posuere lacus, vitae tempus lacus tellus a erat. Quisque lacinia laoreet purus sit amet facilisis. Praesent eu elementum leo. Phasellus consectetur, sapien non accumsan pulvinar, orci eros vehicula est, eget molestie diam dolor id massa. Proin ligula libero, tristique id finibus at, laoreet ac nisi. Morbi porttitor enim non turpis bibendum, id porta libero consectetur. In mattis lectus et urna luctus eleifend.

</div>
<div>
<input type="button" onclick="toggleBodyText()" value="Show Less" id="ButtonShow" />
</div>

<script>
function toggleBodyText() {
var btn=document.getElementById('ButtonShow');
var value=btn.value;
var div = document.querySelector('.bodyText');
if(value=='Show Less') 
{
   div.style.height='300px';
   div.style.overflowX='scroll';
   div.style.overflowY='hidden';
   btn.value='Show More';
}
else 
{
   div.style.height='auto';
   div.style.overflowX='inherit';
   div.style.overflowY='hidden';
   btn.value='Show Less';
}
}
</script>
```